# Groups reluctant to have infinite subgroup

Tags: group-theory, examples-counterexamples

Is there a group with only one infinite subgroup‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌?

Comment: Really I do not remember any example. But it may be trivial! btw, clearly it's torsion if any and it's not product of infintely many finite groups.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

- If you want a group with no proper infinite subgroups then take a Tarski monster group.
- If you want a group with precisely one infinite proper subgroup then take a Tarski monster group $T$ and consider the direct product with a cyclic group of prime order, for example, $G=T\times C_2$.

A Tarski monster group is a finitely generated, infinite [simple](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/848570/10513) group where every proper, non-trivial subgroup is cyclic of order a fixed prime $p$. Hence, when you form $T\times C_2$ the only infinite subgroup you obtain is the copy of $T$. The proof that Tarski monster groups exist is highly non-trivial.

Comment: By a subgroup I do not mean a proper one!

Comment: Then take a Tarski monster by itself...

Answer (score -3):

The circle group $\mathbb{T}$ has only one infinite subgroup. The torsion subgroup of $\mathbb{T}$ is the $n$th roots for unity for all $n$.

Comment: I don't think so! why!? I think it has a countable subgroup.

Comment: Let  $H=\left< e^{qi}\mid q\in \Bbb Q\right>$. Isn't it a proper subgroup of $\Bbb T$?